# Using AutoMapper to map the property of an object to a string

Tags: c#, .net, mapping, automapper, automapper-2

I have the following model:

```
public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to use AutoMapper to map the `Name` property of the `Tag` type to a string property in one of my viewmodels.

I have created a custom resolver to try to handle this mapping, using the following code:

```
public class TagToStringResolver : ValueResolver<Tag, string>
    {
        protected override string ResolveCore(Tag source)
        {
            return source.Name ?? string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

I am mapping using the following code:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Tag, String>()
    .ForMember(d => d, o => o.ResolveUsing<TagToStringResolver>());
```

When I run the application I get the error:

> Custom configuration for members is only supported for top-level
>   individual members on a type.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This is because you are trying to map to the actual destination type rather than a property of the destination type. You can achieve what you want with:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Tag, string>().ConvertUsing(source => source.Name ?? string.Empty);
```

although it would be a lot simpler just to override ToString on the Tag class.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I ended up going with your suggestion to simply override ToString on the Tag class.

Comment: Thanks for this. Out of naivety I was using `ForMember()` when I should have been using `ConvertUsing()`.

Answer (score 16):

ForMember means you are providing mapping for a member where you want a mapping between type. Instead, use this :

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Tag, String>().ConvertUsing<TagToStringConverter>();
```

And Converter is

```
public class TagToStringConverter : ITypeConverter<Tag, String>
{
    public string Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return (context.SourceValue as Tag).Name ?? string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: This helped me to map a whole entity. I had to map a ViewModel to a Entity, and this was the way to go, thanks!