# Mapping between two complex objects with listings with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have two complex objects each has a list in them. I am using AutoMapper to map them together, for example:

```
ConfigurationStore
    .CreateMap<IProcessDefinition, ProcessDefinition>()
    .ForMember(p => p.ProcessDefinitionDomainId, opt => opt.MapFrom(t => t.DomainId))
    .ForMember(p => p.Schemas, opt => opt.MapFrom(t => t.Schemas))
    .ForMember(p => p.ConfigurationValues, opt => opt.MapFrom(t => t.Configs))
    .ForMember(p => p.Libraries, opt => opt.MapFrom(t => t.Libraries));
```

In the given example `t.Schemas` is a list of implementation of `ISchemas` which is a class with name and value members, both are of type `string`. On the other hand, `p.Schemas` is just a list of strings. I have tried resolver approach for so, described here [Using AutoMapper to map the property of an object to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189729/using-automapper-to-map-the-property-of-an-object-to-a-string).

It fails because resolver only works with root objects. I have also tried registering a custom between both the schemas, which didn't work either.

```
t.Schemas = List<string>
p.Schemas = List<ISchema>

public interface ISchema
{
    string name;
    string class;
}
```

Please let me know if you have any advice for me, much appreciate it.

Comment: One tiny thing - you don't need MapFrom on properties whose name are the same. You don't need the Schemas or Libraries pieces (it's kinda the whole point of AutoMapper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another map which transforms an `ISchema` into a `string`, using `ConvertUsing`:

```
ConfigurationStore.CreateMap<ISchema, string>()
.ConvertUsing(s => s.name);;
```

Comment: Ignore the comment above